# Twilio "The SDP is not correctly formatted." when connection SIP

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-api, sdp

I am trying to send SIP from Asterisk to Twilio to start a voice call, but I am getting the error

> "32102" - "The SDP is not correctly formatted.

Request Parameters:

```
SipCallId   "31780c1014c8110130d0d50962cafa11@10.100.0.30"
SipSrcTransport "udp"
UserAgent   "PRACTIS SCOUT/SIP 2.6"
To  "<sip:2410@mytestbot.sip.twilio.com>"
From    "\"PRACTIS\" <sip:PRACTIS@10.100.0.30>;tag=as3923c373"
```

I didn't find a way to get the request body message from Twilio debugger.

I am missing something?

Comment: You have to provide the SDP body if you want to know what's wrong with it

Comment: Are you able to see the SDP that Asterisk sent to Twilio? If you can't see it in the Twilio debugger can you see it in the Asterisk logs or capture it using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue by changing the audio codec on Asterisk. We enabled all the available codecs in Asterisk so Twilio could choose the supported codec.

Thank you for your time!